# How to do SAML authinitication in cordova web view?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ionic-framework

I am developing an app using cordova, Ionic framework. I have some third party client URLs. If the user is enabled for SAML then as soon as he enters username and password then I have to open a page with in the web-view if his SAML authentication is enabled. After that he I will login will happen from that redirected page I will get back the token from server. If Authentication is fine then I have to store that returned token in my app's localstorage and need to show him the home page. Is anyone solved this kind of problem.